# CSS parent and child selector correct syntax

Tags: css, css-selectors, parent-child

I've been seeing CSS like this lately:

**1.**

```
.header {
    position: relative;
    max-height: 1000px;
    z-index: 1;

    .sidebar{
        padding: 25px 25px;
    }

    .menu{

        border-radius:0;
        min-height: 30px;
        height:100px;

        i{
            color:#CCC !important;
            width:40px;
        }
    }
}
```

I guess `header` is the parent class and `sidebar` and `menu` are child classes of `header`.

Is this valid CSS syntax or good practice?

Usually I would expect CSS like this:

**2.**

```
.header { ... }
.header .sidebar { ... }
.header .menu { ... }
```

or even

**3.**

```
.header { ... }
.header > .sidebar { ... }
.header > .menu { ... }
```

What is the difference between these 3 cases?

Comment: Umm the first one is SCSS.

Comment: As Praveen mentioned; the example you're showing SASS, which when compiled into a CSS file would just output what you see in #2 or #3.

Comment: Oh I'm clearly a noob

Comment: @user2456977 Explained the whole thing as an answer for you. Let me know if you understand and you have any questions in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one looks like it's [SCSS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) (or some other CSS Pre-Processor) and not CSS, which render as the #2. To give you an idea of the difference between using `>` and not is:

```
.header .sidebar { ... }
.header .menu { ... }
```

Selects `.sidebar` and `.menu` anywhere inside `.header`.

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="sidebar"></div>
  <div class="menu"></div>
</div>

<div class="header">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="sidebar"></div>
    <div class="menu"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The code works for both the cases above. While, if you use:

```
.header > .sidebar { ... }
.header > .menu { ... }
```

The above code will not the second one that's wrapped inside `.wrap`. The second code is a [direct descendant or a direct child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors).

Answer (score 1):

First structure is SCSS ( a css preprocessor ) . That's the difference between first and 2&3.

> SCSS is a special type of file for SASS, a program written in Ruby that assembles CSS style sheets for a browser. SASS adds lots of additional functionality to CSS like variables, nesting and more which can make writing CSS easier and faster. SCSS files are processed by the server running a web app to output a traditional CSS that your browser can understand.

The difference between 2&3 is the use of `>` which means " direct child selector " . For example `.header .sidebar` will select all `.sidebar` that are inside `.parent` regardless if they are children or grandchildren etc.

```
 <parent>
   <child></child>
   <child>
      <grandchild></grandchild>
   </child>
 </parent>
```

So it will select child and grandchild and further down the tree.

Using `>` will only select the `child` not the `grandchild`

Comment: How can you be so sure it's SCSS over any other CSS preprocessor?

Comment: Also, SCSS is not a CSS extension, but it's a CSS Pre Processor.

Comment: saying `it is SCSS` is not wrong. I am not 100% sure. But it can be. Can you prove it's not ? SCSS it's the most used. It can be LESS. or others. That doesn't mean my assumption that is SCSS is incorrect. @PraveenKumar my bad, SASS is the extension